# Resize Range array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a Range array declared

```
Dim aRange(1 to 5) as Range
```

I am unable to resize the array later on in my code using

```
ReDim Preserve aRange(1 to a)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or am I unable to resize a Range array.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
Dim aRange(1 to 5) as Range 'Static dimensioning, cannot be changed later on
```

by:

```
Dim aRange() as Range 'Declared as dynamic array, have to be redim before using it
```

So:

```
Dim a as Integer
a = 6    

Dim aRange() as Range 'Declared as dynamic array, have to be redim before using it

ReDim Preserve aRange(1 to 5)
ReDim Preserve aRange(1 to a)
```

See **[ReDim Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266231%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)**